# Using pivot in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this table:

```
Name        Occupation
Samantha    Doctor
Julia       Actor
Maria       Actor
Meera       Singer
Ashely      Professor
Ketty       Professor
Christeen   Professor
Jane        Actor
Jenny       Doctor
Priya       Singer
```

I want to have this output:

```
    Doctor     Professor    Singer   Actor
    Jenny       Ashley      Meera    Jane
    Samantha    Christeen   Priya    Julia
    NULL        Ketty       NULL     Maria
```

I want to convert the occupation rows into columns and then list the names by occupation.
I've been trying with `pivot` relational operator but the first argument we pass into `pivot` should be an aggregate function so I'm not sure if that is the best way to solve this query.
This is the query that I've been working using `pivot` but of course as I'm using `max(name)` it's just returning one name:

```
select * from occupations 
pivot (max(name) for occupation in ([doctor],[actor],[singer],[professor])) 
as pvt
```

This is my output using the query above:

```
doctor      actor   singer  professor
Samantha    Maria   Priya   Ketty
```

Can I use `pivot` relational operator to solve this?? What changes could I do?

Comment: instead of `select * from occupations` use `select * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by occupation order by (select null)) rn from occupations) o`. you want to assign a row_number or something like that to make each row distinct. edit: if you don't want to have the row number show up in the final result set, just select specific columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am inclined to approach these problems using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then Name end) as doctor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then Name end) as actor,
       max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then Name end) as singer,
       max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then Name end) as professor     
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by occupation order by name) as seqnum
      from thistable t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

This SQL

```
with data as (
    select * from (values
         ('Samantha', 'Doctor')
        ,('Julia',    'Actor')
        ,('Maria',    'Actor')
        ,('Meera',    'Singer')
        ,('Ashely',   'Professor')
        ,('Ketty',    'Professor')
        ,('Christeen','Professor')
        ,('Jane',     'Actor')
        ,('Jenny',    'Doctor')
        ,('Priya',    'Singer')
    )t(Name,Occupation)
),
groups as (
    select
        Name,Occupation,
        RowNo = row_number() over (partition by Occupation order by Name)
    from data
)
select
    Doctor,Professor,Singer,Actor
from groups
pivot (max(Name) for occupation in (Doctor,Professor, Singer,Actor) ) as pvt
;
```

yields:

```
Doctor    Professor Singer    Actor
--------- --------- --------- ---------
Jenny     Ashely    Meera     Jane
Samantha  Christeen Priya     Julia
NULL      Ketty     NULL      Maria
```